# Pyspark: Count number of True values per row

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Working in databricks, I've got a dataframe which looks like this:

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
data = [(True, True, True), (True, True, True), (True, False, True)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.display()
```

[image]

I'd like to create a new column "number_true_values" that contains the number of True values per row. Unfortunately, one does not seem to be able to just sum up True and False values in pyspark like in pandas. The code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('number_true_values', sum([F.col(column) for column in df.columns]))
```

throws the exception `AnalysisException: [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.BINARY_OP_DIFF_TYPES] Cannot resolve "(a + 0)" due to data type mismatch: the left and right operands of the binary operator have incompatible types ("BOOLEAN" and "INT").;`

If I had a dataframe that contains numbers instead like the following...

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
data = [(1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.display()
```

[image]

... the syntax from above would work and return the desired result:
[image]

How do I count the number of True values per row in databricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast your columns to `long` and then sum it, so something like this,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('number_true_values', sum([F.col(column).cast("long") for column in df.columns])).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+----+------------------+
|   a|    b|   c|number_true_values|
+----+-----+----+------------------+
|true| true|true|                 3|
|true| true|true|                 3|
|true|false|true|                 2|
+----+-----+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

while the easiest approach is already mentioned, you could also create an array and filter the array based on the value to be counted. it can be used with any value, not just T/F.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('num_true', 
               func.size(func.filter(func.array('a', 'b', 'c'), lambda x: x == func.lit(True)))
               ). \
    show()

# +----+-----+----+--------+
# |   a|    b|   c|num_true|
# +----+-----+----+--------+
# |true| true|true|       3|
# |true| true|true|       3|
# |true|false|true|       2|
# +----+-----+----+--------+
```